Differnce between between ahankara and psychological ego
Ahankara is mentioned as a klesha or affliction in Yoga Sutras.
At the same time, in the modern psychology when talking about "strong ego" it means, among others, good ability for mind-control, exertion of will-power and clear view of one's path and place. To my view it this necessary for a Yogin in this sense.
Are those really two distinct entities ? How would he exert mind control without identification of some kind ? It seems as if exertion of will requires some goal.
It would less of question in case of effortless path. But classical eight-fold Yoga is based on effortful practice, which requires, well, ego-effort.
